# WebStorm: Exclude folders by pattern

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

#### this is how a `.idea/${repo}.iml` looks like:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="WEB_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager">
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.tmp" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/temp" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/tmp" />
      <excludePattern pattern="*.log" />
      <excludePattern pattern="*.lock" />
      <excludePattern pattern="dist/*" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

#### this is a screenshot of my **`preferences > directories`** configuration:

[image]

---

### Expected:

Being able to `mark directories as excluded` by pattern, 
so I can ignore multiple folder at once.
(I use a monorepo and have multiple dist dirs)

### Actual

Files under `dist` are still being indexed, even while the folder dist is marked with a different color.
[image]

---

using `WebStorm 2019.1.3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dist` should work, `dist/*` won't - excluding files/folders by relative path pattern is not supported, see [IDEA-173675](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173675)